# Symfony2 Custom form field for hierarchy in select element

Tags: forms, symfony, tree

I created a custom form field extending de entity field for display a select with hierarchy of destinations. Table destination is a nested tree based on gedmo Nested Tree behavior. It's works fine but i need to show the hierarchy in select options based on tree level. For example:

```
Destination1
--Subdestination
--Subdestination
Destination2
--Subdestination
--Subdestination
----Subdestination
```

I build the tree correctly in custom form field class but i dont know how render properly the options for this select type. I was thinking via form theming override the block {% block choice_widget_options %} but this affect all selects.

How can i do that or there are a best way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

1. you could try to implement `__toString()` function on your entity so ti displays proper number of "---" before label
2. check `vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Bridge\Twig\Resources\views\Form\form_div_layout.html.twig` to see how it workds and override the `{% block choice_widget_expanded %}` block or whichever type of list you use, you need to add `{% form_theme form _self %}` in the .twig file where your form is so the twig will search for overriden blocks in the same file